# Execute bash script so that each command is individually accessible in the shell's command history

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-history

How can I execute a bash script in such a way that each of the commands in the bash script can be selected using
the up arrow after execution?

Example script:

```
#!/bin/bash

command #1
command #2
command #3
```

Now after executing this script, I'd like to be able to select each command individually using the up arrow.

Comment: Do you mean "as if they had been typed at the shell command prompt"?

Comment: @Kusalananda yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of to do this is with:

```
exec < <(cat /path/to/script; echo 'exec </dev/tty')
```

Basically bash is only going to append to history things which come in on STDIN. So the solution is to feed the script to STDIN. The problem then is that after reading the script, bash is going to get EOF, and exit. To solve this we put the `exec </dev/tty` so that it switches STDIN back to the TTY when it's done reading the script.
Unfortunately this does mean that `exec </dev/tty` is going to be the last thing on your history, so you'll have to skip past it. If you want, you can get rid of this by doing `echo 'exec </dev/tty; history -d $((HISTCMD-1))'`. But it starts making the command rather long. But if you're going to add a custom shell function to do this, it might not be a big deal. For example:

```
function infile() {
  exec < <(cat "$1"; echo 'exec </dev/tty; history -d $((HISTCMD-1))')
}
```

Usage would then be:

```
infile /path/to/script
```

Comment: Why is a space required between `<` and `<` in `exec< <(ca...` ?

Comment: the first `<` is a redirection, the second is part of the `<( ... )` [process substition](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) syntax

Comment: To expand on what @JeffSchaller said, without the space, bash doesn't understand that they're separate operations. `<<` is a valid operation in bash, and is used to denote start of a heredoc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version using `dialog`. 
Install if missing with `apt-get install dialog` or `yum install dialog`

Looks something like that:

```
┌────────────────────── Choose one ────────────────────────
│ Move using [UP] [DOWN], [Enter] to select                │  
│ ┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐ │  
│ │                   ls    Do a ls                      │ │  
│ │                   w     Call w                       │ │  
│ │                   who   Start who                    │ │  
│ │                   exit  Exit                         │ │  
│ │                                                      │ │  
│ │                                                      │ │  
│ │                                                      │ │  
│ │                                                      │ │  
│ │                                                      │ │  
│ │                                                      │ │  
│ └──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘ │  
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤  
│               <  OK  >        < Quit >                   │  
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

---

Source:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash    
_temp="/tmp/answer.$$"

dialog --backtitle "Blah menu" --title " Choose one "\
         --cancel-label "Quit" \
         --menu "Move using [UP] [DOWN], [Enter] to select" 17 60 10\
         ls "Do a ls"\
         w "Call w"\
         who "Start who"\
         exit "Exit" 2>$_temp

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
     rm $_temp
     exit $?
fi

menuitem=$(cat $_temp)
rm $_temp
clear
$menuitem
```